# Fullscreen background img combined with Fullscreen repeating background

Tags: css, background, fullscreen

I'm trying to place a fullscreen background image combined with a repeating background image without the use of J-query. Is it possible?

This is the code I use to get my image fullscreen:

```
body {  
background: url(../img/bg1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

But now I want this completely overlapped by a .png image background that needs to have a repeat function, for the simple reason that the .png contains lines which will rescale and look awful on certain screen sizes.

Any ideas?

Already tried:

- Giving html a background and body a background, it will only display one of both.

Comment: Just use body for the background repeat and wrapper div for the background image...

Comment: Doesn't show background, do I add anything to it?
#wrapper{
 background-image: url(../img/background2.png);
 background-repeat: repeat;
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware that multiple backgrounds won't work on ie8 if needed:

http://caniuse.com/multibackgrounds

This answer will work on every browser:

You must give width and height to the elements.

You can see answer here: http://jsfiddle.net/Rc38f/

HTML Code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background-image: url('http://www.colourbox.com/preview/4632391-637684-seamless-small-white-flowers-pattern-background.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
    background: url('http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02403/Jonstockshooting_2403237b.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm <3 Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to include two background images on one tag.

> **How it Works**
>
> Multiple background images can be specified using either the
>   individual background properties or the background shorthand property.

This should be a [Helpful resource](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/) to get you started.

css:

```
body {
    background-image: url(http://www.wallcoo.com/paint/Chiplegal_vector_art/images/%5Bwallcoo.com%5D_vector_art_0seasons.jpg), url(http://nopgc.org/v2/images/body_bg.jpg);
    background-position: top center, center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aQ82J/)